# Set theory and logic proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem: Prove that if the sets $A,B,C \in U$, where $U$ is a universal set, then $A \cap B = A \cup B$ if and only if $A = B$

My attempt:We can show that $A \cap B = A \cup B$ if $A = B$ with the following: $$A \cap B = A \cap A = A = A \cup A = A \cup B$$
I thought this proved the statement, but is there anymore I need to show? Would I need to show the statement the other way around; $A = B$ if $A \cap B = A \cup B$?

Thanks in advanced, I'm trying to really understand logic and set theory, but at times it can be confusing.

Comment: Yes you also need to prove the statement the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the other way to complete your proof. Here is what I'd do:

Assume then $A \cap B = A \cup B$. Now let $x \in A$, this means $x \in A \cup B$, which means it belongs in $A \cap B$. Hence $A\subset B$. In the same way, let $x \in B$ and conclude that $B\subset A$. So $A=B$

On the other way you can use what you already did and prove that if  $A=B$ then  $A \cap B = A \cup B.$

Comment: Alright thanks, with your answer and tetori's I was able to see what to do and understand the logic behind this problem. So for if and only if statements, I would need to prove the statement both ways?

Comment: Great, I'm glad I was helpful. Greetings from Costa Rica.

Answer (score 1):

I will give a hint: If $X\subset Y\subset X$ then $X=Y$. You already know that $A\cap B\subset A\subset A\cup B$. How about the $B$?

Comment: Does that mean what I initially did is sufficient I just need to show it with $B$ instead of $A$?

Comment: I give the hint about the proof of $A\cup B=A\cap B\to A=B$. Your proof of $A=B\to A\cap B=A\cup B$ is right.

Comment: Would I have to use a proof by contradiction to show  A∪B=A∩B→A=B ?

Comment: Maybe possible, but you don't need it. I already give the hint for  it.

Comment: Alright thanks, with your answer and Ramirez's I was able to see what to do and understand the logic behind this problem. So for if and only if statements, I would need to prove the statement both ways?

Comment: Yes, unless one direction is very trivial.